ReferenceError: document is not defined during Next.js build (with use client)
I'm encountering the following error when running npm run build in my Next.js project:
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at createTag (/Users/nuris/WebstormProjects/my-career-portfolio/.next/server/app/page.js:1:694431)

I understand that document is not available during server-side rendering (SSR), but I've searched my entire codebase, and I have no direct references to document. The issue seems to be happening during the prerendering of the page /. Here's the full error message:

Here is also my page.js file in case that might help you:
import AboutSection from "./components/homepage/about";
import ContactSection from "./components/homepage/contact";
import Education from "./components/homepage/education"; // Updated
import Experience from "./components/homepage/experience"; // Updated
import HeroSection from "./components/homepage/hero-section";
import Projects from "./components/homepage/projects";
import Skills from "./components/homepage/skills";

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <div className="space-y-20">
            <section id="hero" className="w-full max-w-[1200px] mx-auto px-4 sm:px-8">
                <HeroSection />
            </section>
            <section id="about" className="w-full max-w-[1200px] mx-auto px-4 sm:px-8">
                <AboutSection />
            </section>
            <section id="experience" className="w-full max-w-[1200px] mx-auto px-4 sm:px-8">
                <Experience />
            </section>
            <section id="skills" className="w-full max-w-[1200px] mx-auto px-4 sm:px-8">
                <Skills />
            </section>
            <section id="projects" className="w-full max-w-[1200px] mx-auto px-4 sm:px-8">
                <Projects />
            </section>
            <section id="education" className="w-full max-w-[1200px] mx-auto px-4 sm:px-8">
                <Education />
            </section>
            <section id="contact" className="w-full max-w-[1200px] mx-auto px-4 sm:px-8">
                <ContactSection />
            </section>
        </div>
    );
}

What I’ve Tried So Far:
I searched the entire project for any document references using WebStorm's global search but found nothing.
I've ensured that components requiring window (like Navbar) use the 'use client' directive.
Environment:
Next.js: 14.2.15
Node.js: 18.x
React: 18.x
Build Command: npm run build
I started this project using a template repository to save time. However, I noticed that the template itself does not successfully build either, and it throws the same ReferenceError: document is not defined error during the npm run build step.
Here is the link to the template repository I used: developer-portfolio
How can I identify the root cause of the document is not defined error if there are no direct document references in my code?
Could this be caused by one of my dependencies, and if so, how can I determine which one?
What is the best way to debug such SSR issues in Next.js projects?

tried on github codespaces and it did build. was using node 20 tho
